# Show list of entries in one table, which doesnt have an entry in a multi/link table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a music festival app. I have three tables, `artists`, `vehicles`, and `vehicleLink`.

`artists` is;

```
| id | name     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | Artist 1 |
| 2  | Artist 2 |
| 3  | Artist 3 |
```

`vehicles` is;

```
| id | type | reg  |
|----|------|------|
| 1  | Car  | REG1 |
| 2  | Van  | REG2 |
| 3  | Car  | REG3 |
```

`vehicleLink` is;

```
| id | artist_id | vehicle_id |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 1  | 1         | 1          |
| 2  | 1         | 2          |
| 3  | 2         | 3          |
```

I can easily show lists of all artists vehicles with the following MySQL;

```
SELECT v.id, v.type, v.reg, a.name AS artist_name
FROM vehicles v
JOIN vehicleLink l ON v.id = l.vehicle_id
JOIN artists a ON l.artist_id = a.id
```

This gives;

```
| id | reg  | type | artist_name |
|----|------|------|-------------|
| 1  | REG1 | Car  | Artist 1    |
| 2  | REG2 | Van  | Artist 1    |
| 3  | REG3 | Car  | Artist 2    |
```

I now need a list where `artist_id` IS NOT present in `vehicleLink` yet. e.g to print a list of people who have yet to give us their vehicle details.

I've scoured StackOverflow and Google but not managed to find anything that worked, I'm just trying this directly in phpMyAdmin. For example adding the below WHERE NOT, returns 0 rows;

```
where not exists (select 1 from artists where id = l.artist_id)
```

Table artists has `id`.
Table vehicleLink has `artist_id`

I need the right query to show which `artists.id` does not appear in `vehicleLink`, which in these examples is Artist 3

Comment: Probaly use a left join

Comment: Could you please add the table columns for convenience of understanding and reference?

Comment: @FaisalRahmanAvash -- have edited to include the 3 relevant tables !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try using not in the id with vehicles

```
select  a.name AS artist_name, a.id AS artist_id 
from artists a where  a.id not IN (
  SELECT  a.id  
  FROM vehicles v
  JOIN vehicleLink l ON v.id = l.vehicle_id
  JOIN artists a ON l.artist_id = a.id

)
```